# Print two arbitrary excel worksheets as one page, double-sided

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel file. It contains several worksheets (ex: A, B, C, D ...). Each worksheet prints on one page in the same orientation.

How do I quickly print any two of these worksheets (ex: A & C, B & C, etc.) as a single page, double-sided?

If I ctrl select the two worksheet tabs and print, Excel will print just those 2 selected worksheets, but they print as separate pages even when the double-sided print option from the Excel print screen is set.

Comment: if you can't manage to work it directly from Excel, try to export to pdf first.

Comment: Did you try to _Ctrl select_ the two worksheets, open a new document, paste there and print? Else I suppose you can overcame with a little macro.

Comment: Ctrl select worksheets (holding Ctrl and clicking on the worksheet tabs) and then copy them to single new worksheet? I tried and did not work. So far, export to PDF seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution, following the @MatheJuhasz comment:

---

1. Select the sheets you would like to print by holding CTRL and
   clicking on individual worksheets.
2. Save those as a .pdf (File->Save as ... -> Save at type:PDF)
3. Print .pdf on both sides, as usually.

---

Tadaaaa!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Had problems with the PDF not saving my Excel gridlines after creating a PDF

I copied the Excel spreadsheet to Word, which gave me gridlines and text. I then saved it as a Word document and printed it. This gave me what I wanted to then fill out the spreadsheet manually, which is what I want for recording data.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Resolved it by 1. ensuring duplex print is set, selecting the required tabs, Select "Print Active Sheets" then, and this is the odd bit, select "Page Setup" then "Options" click "OK" then "OK" again, which seems like you haven't really done anything, then print. This works for me when printing duplex to a Canon Pixma.

Answer (score 0):

(i) Select the sheets you would like to print by holding CTRL and clicking on individual worksheets.
(ii) Go to Print as normal, specify the print range i.e. Pages 1 to 2 , select 'Print Both Sides'  ,  Press Print     :)

Comment: Welcome to SU and thanks, but that's the same answer that maycca already gave!

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above (and this was for Excel 2021), with two sheets selected, I went to the print dialog and saw page 1 print properties had it set to double sided. I then clicked the print preview arrow to go to page 2 and low and behold, saw it change on the left had side to single sided. I changed this to double sided and it worked but noticed on closing down the workbook, it didn't prompt me to save - so Excel thought nothing had changed. You also need to save the workbook.